# drag and drop function onTouch event fails

Tags: java, android

Hi I wrote an app using drag'n drop option, Im using android studio 3 & sdk 26
When I get to the touch event I get the error message:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
Thats the code:

```
private View.OnTouchListener OnTouchListener() {

    return new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            final int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
            final int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                            view.getLayoutParams();
                    xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                    yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
            }
            mainlayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I used that code before and it worked, I cant understand whats wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message the issue has nothing to do with the drag and drop, it looks like this part of code:

**RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                            view.getLayoutParams();**

and

**RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();**

should be changed to :

**LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                            view.getLayoutParams();**

and

**LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();**

You didn't put your xml, but I am supposing that parent of "view" is a LinearLayout right?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    tools:context="com.roybindit.user.animals_dragdropgame.GameBoard"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout">

Comment: Alright, I think in this case the touch is propagated to the children of your view. If you are interested in the touch inside a specific view maybe you should add a sort of test before using the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams. Something like if(view == my specefic view) then put the rest of the code.

Comment: I'll try it, tnx :-)